# IntelliJ IDEA -GIT change terminal

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am trying to change the Terminal of IntelliJ IDEA from the default cmd.exe to Git for Windows' shell. I have change the path to:

"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i.
but when I do that either I get this error...
-java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY
or the console opens and closes right away.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Do you use any antivirus software? Also please attach screenshot from "Settings | Tools | Terminal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was finally working: 
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i

I was just using a different language for "Program Files" therefore the error.